# change the text color of Time Picker [android]

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, timepicker, textcolor

How can I Change the Text color of Time picker in android .....
I am having a black shadow background in my application and by default the time in Time picker is also in black so the time is not visible....
[image]

The default view of the time picker is

[image]

my XMl Entry is :

```
  <TimePicker
                    android:id="@+id/timePicker"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

android Java code is :

```
timePicker  = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    timePicker.setCurrentHour(hour);

    timePicker.setCurrentMinute(minute);
```

Comment: Could you please put some code...?

Comment: @V.J. i edited with code  also...

Comment: actually u want change of text color but where is text in your code?

Comment: here is an example. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

Comment: @ SubbaReddy PolamReddy The text is not visible due to the background black color ..... can  i change the same text color into white or any visible color

Comment: Check this link, hope it help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969513/how-can-i-override-timepicker-to-change-text-color

Comment: this post may help you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837480/android-honeycomb-datepicker-text-color

Comment: @stiffler any final answer that you got?

Comment: @Ads no I didn't got ......

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own XML layout for the datepicker as in the example [here](http://custom-android-dn.blogspot.fr/2013/03/how-to-create-custom-date-time-picker.html).

Not sure how well this will play with your activity if it is extending FragmentActivity, but should give you a start in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **res > values > themes.xml** and add an item inside **style** tag with attribute **"android:textColorPrimary"** and set the color you want.

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
```