# How can I Change TimePicker Text Color in xml or code

Tags: android, styles

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969513/how-can-i-override-timepicker-to-change-text-color) link about changing the text color of TimePicker but I didn't benefit from it

I used this code

```
<style name="MyTimePicker1" parent="@android:style/Widget.TimePicker">
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    </style>
```

and I get this error

```
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Widget.TimePicker'.
```

I also tried this code

```
void applyFontRecursively(ViewGroup parent, Integer textColor) 
    {    
        for(int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++)
        {
            View child = parent.getChildAt(i);            
            if(child instanceof ViewGroup) 
            {
                applyFontRecursively((ViewGroup)child, textColor);
            }
            else if(child != null)
            {


                     if(child instanceof TextView)
                    {
                         TextView textView = (TextView) child;
                         textView.setTextColor(textColor);

                    }
            }                
        }
    }
```

and I get this result

[image]

Comment: I tried your applyFontRecursively(..) function it worked for me thanks...

Comment: It didn't work fot all texts, did you used the same code ?